# PHP object to array using self

Tags: php, oop

How would I alter the below code so that it returns itself as an array. E.g using $this

```
    public function toArray($data) {

        if (is_array($data) || is_object($data)) {

            $result = array();

            foreach ($data as $key => $value){
                $result[$key] = $this->toArray($value);
            }

            return $result;
        }

        return $data;           
    }
```

So that instead of passing the `$data` it converts all the private properties from `$this` into an array.

Comment: Why not just use `type cast`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? [get_object_vars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

```
$data = get_object_vars ($this);
```

also you can do like this([typecast](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting)):

```
$data = (array)$this;
```

Those two are a little different